# Error: Invalid HTTP method in community SSO

Tags: community, single-sign-on

Have set up my community SSO by referring [Configure SSO Across Multiple Salesforce Orgs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sso.meta/sso/sso_examples_sf2sf.htm). After that when I try to login I am getting below error.

```
Error: Invalid HTTP method
```

I tried to have set up the as mentioned in SSO documentation but still facing the issue. Community I try to access community the endpoint I am getting error. Do anyone have any idea how to resolve this issue.

[image]
[image]